# How to make certain block of HTML code repeatable using Javascript or other Java method?

Tags: javascript, java, android, html

I'm creating android apps using Ionic which combines HTML and Javascript. My question is what is best method for making my questions (highlighted one #picture 2) to be repeated after the "Add" button being clicked.

So far i have tried to learn how to write html codes inside javascript. I am hoping to copy the block of HTML code inside my javascript so that i can use Do while or maybe If Statement to make it repeatable. Other than that, i don't really know. Hoping you guys can help me on this one by giving my idea and maybe example.

This is the original picture of my apps
[image]

The part that i want it to repeat everytime the button "Add" being clicked is the highlighted one
[image]

If you guys don't understand my questions, please tell me right away. It's hard to describing it actually.

Comment: maybe this an ionic question, since it really depends on your JS framework how to do it. maybe add ionic tag.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you right,you can do that using jquery append method

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you just need to add a loop and on each iteration you will need to append the question(subject) coded in html.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
    function load()
    {
        var numQuestions = 5;
        var data="";
        for(var i=0;i<numQuestions;i++)
        {
            data+="<font color='red'>Question #"+i+"</font><br/>";
            for(var answerIndex=0;answerIndex<4;answerIndex++)
            {
                data+="<input type='radio' name='question"+i+"'/> Answer #"+answerIndex+"<br/>";
            }
            data+="---------------------------------------<br/>";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;
    }
 </script>
<body onload="load()">

<p id="demo">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>

</body>
</html>
```

You can use different elements, styles or even data structures for different types of questions/answers